# Custom Validation on Text Field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to validate using a `Regex` and make own validation for start with the `com.`,Could you please advise me with some example I want Validation on Text field.
Text field must be start with **com.**

```
<input id="appPackage" name="appName" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt1">
```

I have tried below code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("appPackage", function(value, element) {
        return jQuery.validator.methods['appPackage'].call(this, value, element) || value == ("com.");
    }, "Please enter a valid with (com.)."); // connect it to a css class jQuery.validator.addClassRules({ appPackage : { appPackage : true } });
```

[Text Field input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoIZ.jpg)

Comment: use jquery validator with rezex

Comment: show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp - Have fun

Comment: // add a method. calls one built-in method, too.
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("appPackage", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery.validator.methods['appPackage'].call(
     this,value,element
    )||value==("com.");
   }, "Please enter a value with (com.)."
  );
  
  // connect it to a css class
  jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
   appPackage : { appPackage : true }    
  });

Comment: You're a member of this site for more than 4 years and could figured out how to [edit] your post by now.

Comment: you can also create a custom submit function and check the value: document.getElementById('inputElement').value.startsWith("com")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check working `regex` in this link :[Working Regex](https://regex101.com/r/aF1e5b/1)

Try below solution:

```
$.validator.addMethod("appName", function(value, element) {
    var val = ''
    //  var customError = "";
    if (value.match(/^com\./))
    {
        val = true;
    } else {
        val = false;
    }

    return val;
}, 'Please enter a valid app name which start with (com.).');
```

> HTML CODE:

```
<input id="appPackage" name="appName" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt1">
```

Comment: `.` needs to be escaped because it is a wildcard in Regex.

Comment: @PeterB , i am not good enough in regex , can you please edit my answer , if i am wrong in regex

Comment: @UmerBest,  there is minor change in regex , let me find out and update the answer,

Comment: yes I checked thank you so much for your time. @chiragsatapara

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code to validate.

```
var value=document.getElementById("your_field_id").value;
var n = value.startsWith("com");
```

Here `n` will be the boolean value that return true if valid data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var SiteAddress = "com.url.abc";
var SiteAddressTemp = "abc.com.url.abc";
var SiteAddressRegx = /^com/;
alert(SiteAddressRegx.test(SiteAddress));   //true
alert(SiteAddressRegx.test(SiteAddressTemp ));   //false
```